# Why does MySQL value get deleted at the click of browser's 'back' button?

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone explain to me why this happens?

I have a file called `profile.php`, where I want to echo out a user's photo by reading its file path from MySQL. The code is below:

`echo "<img src=\"{$row['PortraitPath']}\" />"`;

Some of the code that represents how a file path for the photo is saved is presented below (`uploader.php`):

```
$sess_userid = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['userid']);
$Image = mysql_real_escape_string($prod_img_thumb);
$PortraitPath = mysql_real_escape_string($prod_img_thumb);

$query  = "UPDATE Members 
            SET PortraitPath = '$PortraitPath',
                Image = '$Image'
            WHERE fldID='$sess_userid'"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$query);

mysql_close($con);
```

Now, I am ABLE to properly save the file path to my database, but what I noticed was that as soon as I click the 'back button' on my browser, the file path will be deleted from MySQL, and hence, I won't be able to display the picture no longer on `profile.php`. Whereas, if I decide to manually type in profile.php for the website, the file path won't be deleted. Can someone explain to me why this happens and how I may be able to get around it?

Thank you.

Comment: Only way the data could be deleted from MySQL is because of using a DELETE query - what happens when the page loads (doesn't matter if from going there or using the back button)?

Comment: When the page loads on uploader.php, the uploaded photo will be shown. When the page loads on profile.php, a photo which was uploaded and saved to MySQL is supposed to be shown but depending on how you navigate to it (back button, it won't show).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to guess that it is because you call the `uploader.php` again on the same page and the

```
 '$PortraitPath'
```

is set to 0 so it updates it again.